# Reason for MySQL authentication error: Access denied for user 'root'@'xyz.com' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql

I have set up a new back up server on which I have configured LAMP configuration. My web application connects to mysql and stores/fetches the data from mysql. When accessing the web app, it shows me this error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'xyz.com' (using password: YES)

on checking the access details on mysql, it shows

[image]

Also, I restarted the server, but not sure what authentication needs to be provided to make it working.

In addition, this is what I see when I use `ELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();`
`root@localhost`|`root@localhost`

Comment: Share some code so i can help you.

Comment: what is that you need to know, in terms of code?

Comment: I want database settling file

Comment: check your configuration file , where you provide username, password in code.

Comment: @Diksha Is there any specific name for config file? sorry, i'm doing this for the first time, no idea about this

Comment: @user4943236 are you using any framework/cms or simple core php?

Comment: I'm using simple core php,

Comment: ok then check where you are connecting to database in code.

Comment: I did change the user name and pswd ther.

Comment: @user4943236 pls show that code for better understanding

Comment: @Diksha, updating the host name worked for me as suggested by Green, however the problem is that it looks like the Admin rights have been revoked. so, if I access my application, I am no longer seeing the screens that an admin can see

Answer (score 0):

the details on mysql is "xyz", not "xyz.com", update the host and try again~

Comment: how do I change that? any idea pls

Comment: use root, and try like this: update mysql.user set Host='xyz.com' where User='root' and Host='xyz'

Comment: thanks this worked. but now, the problem is that it is no longer an admin ? how do I do that?

Comment: what is the meaning of "admin"? for the whole MySQL_Server? or only some of the databases? the "Host" column only controls whether a "User" can access the database from a computer/client, other privileges on database is controled by other columns in mysql.user.  Use root and input " show grants for root@'xyz.com'; " , it shows the privileges of root@xyz.com

Comment: It says that `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'xyz.com' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*676243218923905CF94CB52A3C9D3EB30CE8E20D' WITH GRANT OPTION` . By admin means, we have done some gate keeping an only some of the users are able to see all the screens. If I access this, I'm not able to see all the screens.. any idea why it would be the case?

Comment: ALL PRIVILEGES ON \*.\* TO 'root'@'xyz.com'---means 'root' , login from 'xyz.com' has all privileges(super user!) on any databases. if user login from 'xyz.com' with 'root', the user should see all the screens; input "show grants;" , it shows the privileges of current user,  maybe the login User is not "root@'xyz.com' "

Comment: this is what I get on inputting `show grants`: `| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*676243218923905CF94CB52A3C9D3EB30CE8E20D' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION `

Comment: root@'localhost' and root@'xyz.com' should has the same privileges in mysql. What's wrong when login as root@'xyz.com'?

Comment: I'm no longer been an admin now. I'm not able to see all the screen that a superuser should be. Not sure how to resolve this :(

Comment: Actually, root@'localhost' and root@'xyz.com' almost the same Account in mysql. if some screen misses in php-application, check the application's error-log, may find some information.